# localStorage methods

Tags: javascript, local-storage

```
function Todo(id, task, who, dueDate) {
    this.id = id;
    this.task = task;
    this.who = who;
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
    this.done = false;
}    

function updateDone(e) { 
      var spanClicked = e.target;
      var id = spanClicked.parentElement.id;
      var done = spanClicked.parentElement.done;
      spanClicked.innerHTML = "&nbsp;&#10004;&nbsp;";
      spanClicked.setAttribute("class", "done");

      var key = "todos" + done;
      localStorage.setItem(key, "true");
      console.log(key);
    }
```

In the second part of the last function I'm trying to change the value of the done property to "true" when the object I'm targeting is clicked for localStorage. What happens instead though is when I check localStorage in the web console the value of that object doesn't change and instead another object is added to the localStorage called "todosundefined: 'true'". I don't understand why when I click an object something is added to the localStorage as a separate, undefined object instead of changing the value of the object I clicked on. Any suggestions to modify it so that I change the done value of the object I click on for localStorage?

Comment: The variable `done` is undefined. That's what's wrong.

Comment: What would you expect `done` to be? DOM elements have no such properties.

Comment: done is a css class that I assigned to the object. there is another class called "notDone". when the class is set to done, I want to change it to true

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above, there's no `done` property on DOM objects. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but in order to get the contents of the class attribute of a DOM object, you should use the `className` property. E.g:

```
var done = spanClicked.parentElement.className;
```

Then again, that doesn't appear to make any sense based on the code you posted. I'm assuming you want to use local storage to keep track which items on a list of todo's are done. In that case, wouldn't it be better to just store an array of id's of all items that are done (or the reverse)? You can't store an array directly in local storage, but you can use, for example, JSON.stringify() to get a string representation of the array that you can then store.

Comment: When I check local storage now this is what I see: ({id:136, task:"get milk", who:"scott", dueDate:"today",done:"true"}). But, when I type in localStorage to the console I get that again except done is false and there's a separate todo item, with the same id that just says true. i've tried several other ways to try to do this and I get the same answer every time. when i type localStorage into the consel to see what's stored I want to see the object with all the information including done:"true"

Comment: I tried: for ( i = 0; i < spanClicked.length; i++ ){
    var key = id + done;
    localStorage.setItem(key, "done");
  } if (spanClicked.className = "done") {
    var key = spanClicked.parentElement.id;
    localStorage.setItem(key, "done");
  } var key = id + done;
  localStorage.setItem(key, "done");
  console.log(key);

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think I need to see more of your code in order to help you. Perhaps post a link to a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?